# Behind the curtain

Tags: discussion, architecture, optimization

I'd like to read more about design decisions, optimizations, scaling techniques applied during development.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jeff and Jarrod posted self-deprecating answers, but as an outsider, let me tell you that the database code and schema are really tight.  (And I should add that has absolutely nothing to do with me, hahaha.)  If you're going to scale a SQL Server database fast to a large audience at a low cost, you don't want any extraneous business logic in the database.  No triggers, no [UDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Defined_Function)s, no CLR code, no record-by-record operations.

Normally when I do performance tuning for clients, I start tracing queries with a duration of more than 10 seconds.  At Stack Overflow, I have to crank my filters down to 150-200 ms just to see any activity. It always gives me a grin.

Just generally speaking, application servers are cheap, and SQL Server is expensive ($5k-$25k per CPU).  Even if you use open source databases, it's easier to scale application servers than it is to scale database servers.  Every added web/application server is relatively easy to implement with a load balancer - every added database server, not so much.  Every time you have to do anything even remotely CPU-related, do it in the web/application tier, not the database tier.

Comment: *Blush* - You are too kind, sir!

Comment: No, you're just too fast. ;-)

Comment: But how many queries does this structure require for an average pageview?

Answer (score 7):

A typical night of development:

> **Jeff**: Let's see the latest feature.
>   **Me/Dalgas**: Here you go!
>   **Jeff**: What is that? I don't know what that's supposed to be..
>   **Me/Dalgas**: Isn't that what you wanted?
>   **Jeff**: But there's no words on it..
>   **Me/Dalgas**: Want us to redo it?
>   **Jeff**: No.. no time.. we'll do it live - [DO IT LIVE.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2tJjNVVwRCY)

I wouldn't have it any other way.

Comment: Hey, best place to test is always in production....

Comment: Exactly - this meta site is a testament to that philosophy :)

Comment: Something like this?
http://www.projectcartoon.com/cartoon/2

Comment: Bwahaha, yeah, I can just imagine.

Comment: Closed as historical interest.

Comment: @kevin notification received.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely listen to the podcasts - Jeff gives away a lot of stuff in them.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Comment: It's funny as hell, although I'm more interested in that particular 'all-nighter'. ;)